# Swing application implementing runnable - the local variable is not used

Tags: java, swing, oop, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to get my Swing application to run but when I try to run my code, it doesn't run because of the warning "the local variable is not used", how do i fix this?

```
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

       public class RunTraceFile implements Runnable {

          public void run(){
             TraceFile c = new TraceFile();
       }


       public static void main(String [] args){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RunTraceFile());
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not true. Warnings don't prevent code from running, they're just warnings.

Comment: a warning doesn't prevent code from compiling or running. You can "solve" this issue, by using the local variable c.

Comment: if you are not using new created `TraceFile` object anywhere then why are you referencing it, just remove `TraceFile c = ` from your source code to remove the warning

Comment: it probably does run, warnings don't prevent anything, they are just warnings. Try to add something more to see if it works (like `System.out.println("I'm working");` followed by `sleep()` or something else to prevent the console from closing

Comment: This code is working fine, you just need to put some logic/statements to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I fixed it. I realized that I didn't have `setVisible(true);` in the constructor of my TraceFile.